# Prevent Allow Shared Access Key using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

Hey i am currently using Terraform v0.12.28 and provider azurerm v2.22.0 i wanted to Disable (Allow Shared Access Key, Allow Blob public access, and use TLS1_2) in Azure Storage Configuration to make it secure, i found "allow_blob_public_access = false" and "min_tls_version = "TLS1_2" but unable to find parameter to disable  Allow Shared Access Key.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  account_tier             = var.account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.account_replication_type
  allow_blob_public_access = false
  min_tls_version = "TLS1_2"
  

}
```

Comment: don't see it either. You probably should create a feature request here https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: no it did not resolve my issue but yes seem like there is no option to set it to disable through terrafrom script as far as i did research and you guys provide me other way to do it. happy to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to set the **Allow Shared Access Key** in Terraform, it simply means Terraform does not support this feature and this feature in Azure is also the preview version. There is another way to set the **Allow Shared Access Key** beside the Azure portal.

This way is to use the Azure CLI through the `local-exec` in Terraform:

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az resource update --ids ${azurerm_storage_account.main.id} --set properties.allowSharedKeyAccess=false"
  }
}
```

You can get more details about **Allow Shared Access Key** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/shared-key-authorization-prevent?tabs=portal).

Answer (score 2):

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "st" {
...
  shared_access_key_enabled = false
...
}
```

`shared_access_key_enabled` (optional) indicates whether the storage account permits requests to be authorized with the account access key via Shared Key. If false, then all requests, including shared access signatures, must be authorized with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). The default value is true.

Comment: please could you add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: yes :)
shared_access_key_enabled - (Optional) Indicates whether the storage account permits requests to be authorized with the account access key via Shared Key. If false, then all requests, including shared access signatures, must be authorized with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). The default value is true.

Comment: The latest version of Terraform registry documentation for [azurerm_storage_account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account) shows `shared_access_key_enabled` as an option for the `azurerm_storage_account`.  Search the page for `shared_access_key_enabled` to see the description of this option.  It defaults to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature in newer version of the provider. I believe introduced in 2.73:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account#shared_access_key_enabled

Answer (score 0):

[shared_access_key_enabled](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account#shared_access_key_enabled) did not seems to be working you can write own implementation

```
resource "terraform_data" "shared_access_key_enabled_override" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      if [[ "${var.storage_account_config.shared_access_key_enabled}" == "false" ]]; then
        az storage account update --name ${var.storage_account_config.name} --resource-group ${var.storage_account_config.resource_group_name} --allow-shared-key-access false
      else
        az storage account update --name ${var.storage_account_config.name} --resource-group ${var.storage_account_config.resource_group_name} --allow-shared-key-access true
      fi
    EOF

  }
  triggers_replace = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }

}
```